# LINQ Datatable return 0 instead of null coalescing

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ statement which is calculating 3 values from a data table. Sometimes some of these values may contain null. How do i do the equivalent of coalescing the null to a 0.

```
var striko2scrap = from myrow in Scrap.AsEnumerable()
                   where myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 2"
                   group myrow by myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 2" into g
                   select new
                   {
                        TotalScrap = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int?>("Runners") ?? 
                                         0 + x.Field<int?>("HouseIngots") ?? 
                                         0 + x.Field<int?>("Other") ?? 
                                         0)
                   } ;
```

I have tried the ?? 0 in different places but when I debug I still get the same result.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you face is operator precedence. I think what you want to do is handle a `null` as `0`. That would be:

```
int? a = null;
int? b = 1;
int? c = 2;

int result = (a ?? 0) + (b ?? 0) + (c ?? 0); // 3
```

What you wrote is the equivalent of

```
int result = a ?? (0 + b) ?? (0 + c) ?? 0; // 1
```

So all you have to do is to modify the `g.Sum(x => ...)` and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like using the `HasValue` and `Value` properties of nullable value types, which would be:

```
select new
{
    TotalScrap = g.Sum(x => 
      (x.Field<int?>("Runners").HasValue ? x.Field<int?>("Runners").Value : 0 ) +
      (x.Field<int?>("HouseIngots").HasValue ? x.Field<int?>("HouseIngots").Value : 0 ) +
      (x.Field<int?>("Other").HasValue ? x.Field<int?>("Other").Value : 0 )
)};
```

But if you like the `??` notation you could use:

```
select new
{
    TotalScrap = g.Sum(x => 
      (x.Field<int?>("Runners") ?? 0 ) +
      (x.Field<int?>("HouseIngots") ?? 0 ) +
      (x.Field<int?>("Other") ?? 0 )
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var striko2scrap = from myrow in Scrap.AsEnumerable()
                   where myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 2"
                   group myrow by myrow.Field<string>("MachineID") == "Striko 2" into g
                   select new
                   {
                        TotalScrap = g.Sum(x => 
                            (x.Field<int?>("Runners") ?? 0) +
                            (x.Field<int?>("HouseIngots") ?? 0) +
                            (x.Field<int?>("Other") ?? 0))
                   } ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
x.Field<int?>("Runners").Value ?? 0
```

or

```
x.Field<int?>("Runners").HasValue ? x.Field<int?>("Runners") : 0
```